# Is there any shortcut to create regions on RAD Studio 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I want to use regions in my code:

```
{$REGION 'Comment'}
  // Code
{$ENDREGION}
```

Is there any shortcut to create them directly instead of using the mouse to select the menu?
Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not natively, no.  But you should be able to define a custom [Live Template](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Live_Templates) to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Write the region first.
then press shortcut = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>